# Pure JavaScript alternative to jQuerys .find

Tags: javascript

I have this in jQuery:

```
$(document).bind("click touchstart", function(e) {
if (e.target.class != searchControls && !searchControls.find(e.target).length) {
 //do something
});
});
```

What this does is checks the click and if it's not the search element a child of that element, then I can run something. What I'm trying to do is find a pure JavaScript alternative to this.

So far I have:

```
var searchTrigger = document.querySelector(".header__search-btn"),
    productSearch = document.querySelector(".product-search"),
    searchControls = document.querySelectorAll(".product-search__positioner");

document.onclick = function (e) {
 if (e.target.class != searchControls && e.parentNode != searchControls)
   // do something
 }
}
```

However this still fires my function inside the `if` statement, so clearly I'm going wrong—not sure how wrong. Help appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is `searchControls`? DOM elements don't have a `class` property, only `className`. So I would expect `searchControls` to be a string, but then your other uses of `searchControls` don't make sense.

Comment: @hindmost: What makes you think the title was wrong?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the part where I'm settings my variables

Comment: Ah. `document.querySelectorAll` returns a collection of DOM elements. `e.target.class != searchControls` doesn't make sense at all (ignoring that `target.class` doesn't even exist). Also, an event object doesn't have a `parentNode` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a **collection** of DOM elements. `e.target.class != searchControls` doesn't make sense (ignoring that `target.class` doesn't even exist): Assuming you mean `className`, you are trying to compare a **string** with a list of DOM elements. That will always be `false`.

So lets ignore that part and look at `e.parentNode != searchControls`. The event object doesn't have a property `parentNode`. Again, even if you meant `e.target.parentNode`, it would  not make much sense, since you are testing whether a single element is identical to a list of elements.

Based in your use of `.find`, you basically want to know whether a node is contained in another node. Every DOM node has a method [`.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains), so all you have to do is iterate over the collection of DOM elements and call that method:

```
var contained = false;
for (var i = 0; i < searchControls.length; i++) {
    if (searchControls[i].contains(e.target)) {
        contained = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

This can easily be moved into its own reusable function.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `e.target.class`. If you are checking for class name then it should be

```
e.target.className
```

Then to check for parent elements class name

```
 e.target.parentNode.className
```

if you are looking to search inside the parent node then use

```
e.target.parentNode.querySelector("pass your selector here")
```

if you want to search for just child elements:

```
e.target.querySelector("pass your selector here")
```